# Android Studio Stuck on startup

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Hi All,

Does any of you face this problem before? My Android studio stuck on startup. I've tried restart/shut down. Btw, my android studio version is 1.5 on mac

Comment: This question isn't suitable for stackoverflow.. even if it was, with the information provided.. there could be a million and two reasons for this to occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you experience system crash or system auto restart, then please be patient. It take sometime to startup and everything will back to normal :) cheer!

Comment: System crashed and Updated to 1.5.1 and it is working now!

Answer (score -1):

You should go to the %appdata% and delete InteliJ folder, after that run program as administrator.
This is probably caused by:

- No space on partition
- No write permission in %appdata%
- Bug

If it does not work, try to reinstall.

... 1 more!

- Slow write speed or compute speed so it takes much more time as usual.

Comment: the question was about mac